# Get value of specific data-attribute of closest element containg it gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, closest, selectors-api, getattribute

In my library I want to write a little function for `closest()` and especially get the value of a specific `data-attribut` of closest element because in my Application I need to use this very very often. :D

But I only get told by the console:

> TypeError: x.getAttribute is not a function

```js
var $ = function(s) {
  var x;
  var obj = {
    myLib(s) {
      return x || querySelectorAll(s);
    },
    myFunction(s) {
      if (s.startsWith('data-')) { // in this block is sth. wrong
        x = [x[0].closest('*["' + s + '"]')];
        return x.getAttribute(s);
      } else {
        x = [x[0].closest(s)];
        return this;
      }
    }
  };
  x = obj.myLib(s);
  return obj;
};

////////// usage examples

// get the value of attribute "data-wrestler"
var dv = $('.kilo').myFunction('data-wrestler');
console.log(dv);

// select the closest element by selector
var ce = $('.kilo').myFunction('.uniform');
console.log(ce);

// would select the closest element with specific data-attribut by selector
var da = $('.kilo').myFunction('*["data-wrestler"]');
console.log(da);
```

```html
<div id="foxtrott">
  foxtrott
  <div class="uniform" data-wrestler="hulkster">
    uniform
    <div class="charlie">
      charlie
      <div class="kilo">
        kilo
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` should be `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: Before the `x.getAttribute(..)` call you have this statement `x = [x......]` which means that `x` is an array and arrays don't have a `getAttribute` function.

Comment: when that is fixed you will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'closest' on 'Element': '*[\"data-wrestler\"]' is not a valid selector.",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Quotes `[data-wrestler]` - remove them  `x = [x[0].closest('[' + s + ']')];`
2. You use document.querySelectorAll - it returns a collection so you need to use [0]

   return x[0].getAttribute(s);

or change to document.querySelector